# NodeJS fs.mkdirSync returning EPERM error in Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, file-permissions, fs

First I want to clarify that `.mkdirSync(...)` is being used instead of `.mkdir(...)` because it must be completed before further operations take place, and it only occurs once at application (server) initialization.

Here is my code, which seems straightforward enough to me:

```
var fs = require('fs');
try {
  fs.mkdirSync('./logs');
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

But it is giving this error at console, and *not* creating the needed directory:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'c:\my\dev\path\logs'

Most confusingly, this worked exactly once, last night, and I have no idea why.  I deleted the directory this morning to validate the supposedly working code, and *now* the error is appearing.  Any idea what I need to do differently to make it work every time?  My solution also needs to work in Linux.  (Yes, my dev environment is a different OS than my production, it's a bit beyond my control at the moment.)

Comment: Try run CMD as Administrator and start your code again. Should work. This is definitely permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I noticed that the .../logs directory I thought had been deleted was *intermittently* appearing and disappearing, and even an admin account, running CMD as admin, could not view or modify anything about the phantom directory, tho it did appear in a `dir` command.  I was able to *intermittently* see the directory in CMD with `dir`, Git Bash with `ls -l` which showed drwxr-xr-x for .../logs, and in File Explorer.  Closing all running applications that might have been interacting with the directory had no effect.

I restarted my computer and everything just started working again.

I realize that this is not a very helpful StackOverflow question/answer.  This adventure has colored my opinion of the Windows OS in general, though.  Maybe someone can learn from that.  File and directory permissions generally shouldn't be affected by system restarts, and if the file is ENOENT the OS should know whether that is the case or not.